# Не выполняется обновление данных , хоть и логи говорят об обратном

Tags: java, spring, junit, h2, jpql

Я пишу небольшой сервис обмена сообщениями. На данный момент занимаюсь написанием репозитория для работы с данными пользователя. В репозиторий я реализовал все необходимые для работы с БД методы , в том числе и методы которые обновляют данные. Они используют кастомные JPQL запросы для обновления данных. Однако они почему то не работают

**Класс Репозитория**

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    // READ
    Optional<User> findById(Long id);

    Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName);

    Optional<User> findByCryptoWalletAddress(String cryptoWalletAddress);

    Optional<User> findByHashUserFile(String hashUserFile);

    @Query("SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.betaTestKey.key = :key")
    Optional<User> findByBetaTestKey(String key);

    // UPDATE
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.hashUserFile = :file WHERE u.id = :uid")
    void updateHashUserFile(@Param(value = "uid") Long userId, @Param(value = "file") String file);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.userName = :newUserName WHERE u.id = :userId")
    void updateUserName(Long userId, String newUserName);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.cryptoWalletAddress = :newCryptoWalletAddress WHERE u.id = :userId")
    void updateCryptoWalletAddress(Long userId, String newCryptoWalletAddress);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.onlineNetStatus = :newStatus WHERE u.id = :userId")
    void updateNetStatus(Long userId, @Param("newStatus") NetStatus newStatus);

    // DELETE
    void deleteById(Long id);

    void deleteByUserName(String username);

    void deleteByCryptoWalletAddress(String cryptoWalletAddress);

}
```

При тестировании оказалось что методы для обновления в данном классе не работают. А точнее работают с аномалией ,  объясню. При запуске теста в консоли отладки я вижу соответсвующие логи которые потверждают обновления данных в БД.

```
... 
2023-10-21 23:16:48.435 DEBUG 25144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into users (id, beta_test_key, crypto_wallet, hash_data, net_status, pub_key, username) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into users (id, beta_test_key, crypto_wallet, hash_data, net_status, pub_key, username) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-10-21 23:16:48.492 DEBUG 25144 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update users set hash_data=? where id=?
Hibernate: update users set hash_data=? where id=?
2023-10-21 23:16:48.518  INFO 25144 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Committed transaction for test
...
```

Особенно бросается в глаза лог `Committed transaction for test` который говорит что транзакция была закоммичена в БД , а значит по идее данные должны быть обновлены. Однако при запуске теста , данные не обновляются и объекты равны. Мой тестовый метод

```java
    @Test
    void testUpdateHashUserFile(){
        User userBeforeUpdate = this.userRepository.saveAndFlush( (generateOnlyOneUser()) );
        assertNotNull( userBeforeUpdate);


        Long userID = (userBeforeUpdate.getId());
        this.userRepository.updateHashUserFile( userID , "sgljwofjwofiwoifhwoifwifhwoifhwoifh");
        this.userRepository.flush();
    

        User userAfterUpdate = this.userRepository.findById(userID).orElse(null);

        assertNotNull(userAfterUpdate);
        assertNotEquals(userBeforeUpdate , userAfterUpdate); // Здесь валится тест 
        assertNotEquals( (userBeforeUpdate.getHashUserFile()) , (userAfterUpdate.getHashUserFile()) );

    }
```

В данном тесте как видно я пытаюсь обновить поле `hashUserFile` у объекта User , проблема в том что после того как я пытаюсь достать обновленный объект из БД , объект который достается эквивалентен объекту который я сохранил до обновления. Почему так происходит если мы видим соответствующие логи об успешном обновлений данных ? У объекта User перегружен метод `equals()` и `hashCode()`. Я также использовал `flush()` и `saveAndFlush()` что отправить изменения в БД.

**Класс User**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    @Size(min = 6, max = 8)
    @NotBlank
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "crypto_wallet")
    @NotBlank
    private String cryptoWalletAddress;
    @Column(name = "pub_key")
    @NotBlank
    private String publicUserKey;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "net_status")
    private NetStatus onlineNetStatus;

    @Column(name = "hash_data")
    @NotBlank
    private String hashUserFile;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "beta_test_key", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private BetaTestKey betaTestKey;


   // Constructors / Other code ...
```

Да я знаю что можно не писать кастомные запросы обновления , а использовать обычный `save()` встроенный в Spring JPA , однако в данном случае хотел бы использовать краткий запрос на обновление данных. Версия Spring `2.6.15` , используемая БД `h2db` версия `2.2.220`. Полные исходники можете посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/Nicki-afk/sapphire/tree/NJ/(%231)-user-repository). Заранее благодарю

Comment: Видимо, для JPA недостаточно информации, чтобы определить - меняются закешированные сущности. Поэтому в кеше остается старое состояние, хотя в базе уже новое. Попробуйте https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation#clear

Comment: @kami          Спасибо за информацию ! И вправду данные в кеше не обновлялись. После установления флага `clearAutomatically = true` у аннотаций `@Modifying` данные в кеше стираются и повторно запрашиваются с БД при **SELECT** запросе. Однако немного не понятно почему Hibernate видя запрос на обновления данных , и выполняя его не обновляет при этом кеш   .

Comment: а откуда хибер узнает, какие именно сущности будут обновлены в запросе? Может запрос вообще касается структур в БД, которые не имеют отображения в классы приложения. Ну и - раз получилось, было бы неплохо оформить это ответом в назидание идущим следом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось куда более простым. Оказывается Hibernate не обновлял сущности в кеше и в этом была вся проблема. Спасибо [@kami](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192901/kami) который посоветовал источник.
Требовалось установить флаг `clearAutomatically = true`. Tаким образом мы говорим Hibernate что следует очистить кеш и запросить данные повторно при необходимости.

```java
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically  = true)
    @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.hashUserFile = :file WHERE u.id = :uid")
    void updateHashUserFile(@Param(value = "uid") Long userId, @Param(value = "file") String file);
```